# creating a dropdownlist in the header of the gridview while populating its column data from excel sheet

Tags: .net, vb.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, datagridviewcolumn

I need to create a gridview  which

1. fills its column with  data from an excel sheet and
2. for each column in the gridview ,the header should contain a  drop down list with listitems like telephone,name,price which the user will select and set as the header for the particular column.

I imported data into gridview but i am not able to create a drop down list in the gridview.
If i try to create a dropdownlist in the designer page,it is just creating the dropdownlist in the gridview header but not populating the data.So How can i create a dropdownlist in the header of the gridview while populating its column data from excel sheet. Please help.

the code i used to populate data into gridview is

```
Dim con As String = ""
    Select Case Extension
        Case ".xls"
            'Excel 97-03
            con=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Excel03ConString").ConnectionString()
            Exit Select
        Case ".xlsx"
            'Excel 07
            con =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Excel07ConString").ConnectionString()
            Exit Select
    End Select
    con = String.Format(con,Path)
    Dim connExcel As New OleDbConnection(con)
    Dim str As String = "SELECT * From [Sheets$]"
    Dim cmdExcel As New OleDbCommand(str, connExcel)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdExcel)
    Dim dset As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(dset, "Tabledata")
    Dim dtable As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
    GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables(0).DefaultView
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

and  the code to create drop down list is

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>             
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"   AutoPostBack="True">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="name " Value="Description of Goods" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="telephone" Value="Count" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="price" Value="Weight" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Value" Value="Value" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your dataset or datatable is not empty. If there are no rows, nothing will appear. Here's a little test I did and the Ddl appeared in the header. Just run the example as is on a new page.

HTML

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
      <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>
      <HeaderTemplate>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="name " Value="Description of Goods" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="telephone" Value="Count" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="price" Value="Weight" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Value" Value="Value" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TestItem") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
```

VB

```
Public Class DllInGvHeader
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
      Dim tList As New List(Of Test)
      Dim t As New Test
      t.TestItem = 1
      tList.Add(t)
      t.TestItem = 2
      tList.Add(t)
      GridView1.DataSource = tList
      GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
  End Sub

End Class

Public Class Test
  Public Property TestItem As String
End Class
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply. i checked the dataset and the datatable and they are not empty.So how can i bind the columns from the datatatable to the gridview? The above html code is creating the dropdownlist but shouldnt it bind the value from datatable than testitem  as u mentioned (Text='<%# Eval("TestItem") ).I dint undestand the the use of testitem.
is there anyway i can bind data to the itemtemplate from the datasource itself?.

Comment: A couple of things. 1. Make sure AutoGenerateColumns is set to "True" in the Gridview. 2. In your code, "Dim dtable As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)" should be changed to "Dim dtable As DataTable = dset.Tables(0)", which is the dataset you are filling.

Also, Gridview will show all the columns automatically if AutoGenerateColumns is set to True, so if your dataset is not empty, something will show up. Also you don't have to use defaultView, just the dset.Tables(0) would do as the datasource. Once you can view the gridview, note all the column header names, which can be bound using Eval.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. 
1. Make sure AutoGenerateColumns is set to "True" in the Gridview. 
2. In your code, 
"Dim dtable As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)" 
should be changed to 
"Dim dtable As DataTable = dset.Tables(0)", which is the dataset you are filling.

Also, Gridview will show all the columns automatically if AutoGenerateColumns is set to True, so if your dataset is not empty, something will show up. Also you don't have to use defaultView, just the dset.Tables(0) would do as the datasource. Once you can view the gridview, note all the column header names, which can be bound using Eval like in my example before.